# IndexError: list index out of range Multi-threaded server

Tags: python, multithreading, tcp, server

```
from socket import *
import thread


def thread_handler(connectionSocket, addr):
    while True:
        # Establish the connection
            print ("Ready to serve...")

 #           connectionSocket, addr = serverSocket.accept()  



        try:
            message = connectionSocket.recv(1024)
#            print(message, '::', message.split()[0], ":", message.split()[1])
            filename = message.split()[1]
#            print(filename, "||", filename[1:])
            f = open(filename[1:], "r")

            outputdata = f.read()
#            print(outputdata)

            #Send one HTTP header line into socket
            #Fill in start
            connectionSocket.send('\nHTTP/1.1 200 OK\n\n')
            connectionSocket.send(outputdata)
            #Fill in end

            #Send the content of the requested file to the client
            for i in range(0,len(outputdata)):
                connectionSocket.send(outputdata[i:i+1])
            connectionSocket.send(b'\r\n\r\n')

        except IOError:
            #Send response message for file not found
                #Fill in Start
                connectionSocket.send('\nHTTP/1.1 404 Not Found\n\n')
                #Fill in end

                #Close client socket


if __name__ == '__main__':
    serverSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
    # Prepare a sever socket
    serverSocket.bind(("localhost", 6789))
    serverSocket.listen(1)

while True:
    print('waiting for connection...')
    connectionSocket, addr = serverSocket.accept()
    print('...connected from:', addr)
    thread.start_new_thread(thread_handler, (connectionSocket, addr))


serverSocket.close()
```

I understand how the multi threading works now, but I could not figure out how to build a connection.
I'm trying to do a multi-threaded version of TCP server. However, it keeps giving "list index out of range":

```
Ready to serve...
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function thread_handler at 0x10b9750c8>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "http_server_multi.py", line 16, in thread_handler
    filename = message.split()[1]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: I'd suggest using `pdb` to see what `message` is at the time where the index error occurs. Any time you get more than 1024 length input without any whitespace you will get this error.

Answer (score 0):

If nothing is received from the socket because there is no data yet, the `split()` will return `['']` with only on item and the `[1]` on it will fail.

Try to add this before the failing line

```
if not message:
    # time.sleep(0.01)
    continue
```

The `sleep()` call will prevent the thread to use too much CPU, you can umcomment it and adapt the value to your needs.